# Folland Real analysis Exercise 2.4.37

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I want to prove  Exercise 2.4.37 Modes of Convergence in Folland

> Suppose that $f_n$ and $f$ are measurable and $g$ be a function
>
> **1**: if $g$ is continuous and $f_n \to f$ a.e, then $g \circ f_n \to g \circ f$ a.e
>
> **2**: if $g$ is  uniformly continuous and $f_n \to f$ uniformly, almost uniformly, or in the measure, then $g \circ f_n \to g \circ f$ uniformly, almost uniformly, or in the measure

so if you give reasonable hints, I will be very happy. Thanks!

Comment: All these statements follow from definitions. Have you made an attempt? Show us what you have done and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $D$ be the domain of the functions $f$ and $f_n$ and let $N \subseteq D$ be a null-set such that

$f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x \in D \setminus N$. Since $g$ is continuous we have

$g(f_n(x)) \to g(f(x))$  for all $x \in D \setminus N$.

This shows 1.

Are you now in a position to show 2. ?